# Assign value for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to assign `t-sql` expression for each tables row?
For example:

```
Foreach user in Users
{
user.Place = SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Users] AS [t0]
WHERE (COALESCE([t0].[Votes],@p0)) > @p1;
}
```

where `Users` is table. It's pseudo-code but I want to do that in `t-sql` stored procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign sql expression"? Do you want to do this in SQL?

Comment: Can you explain the table structure a little more, and the meaning of the @P0 and @P1 parameters?

Comment: @MikeEast Yeah i want to do it in sql. i mean just assign to row column result of sql query.

Comment: @richardtallent it's not important. Instend of this sql query i can use just SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value] FROM [Users] or something.

Comment: could you post a small example table showing (say) 3-5 rows of the current data, what you want the code above to add to those rows, and whether you're wanting this as some permanent feature, or just for display purposes?

Answer (score 1):

So you want all user records, and with each record, a count..

You can use a subquery - but what are @p0 and @p1?  Check this

```
SELECT u.*, Place = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
    FROM [Users] AS [t0]
    WHERE COALESCE([t0].[Votes],0) > u.Votes)
FROM Users u
```

From SQL Server 2005+, you can use windowing functions

```
SELECT u.*, Place = Rank() over (order by u.Votes)
FROM Users u
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), [RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) or [DENSE_RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

Also have a look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean:

```
UPDATE Users
SET Place = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Users
  WHERE COALESCE(Votes, @p0) > @p1
)
```

?